[iMX93evk]:OpenOCD throws "JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all ones" error
I am trying to enable jtag debugging via openocd on imx93evk, executing the below command
openocd.exe -s share\openocd\scripts -f interface/ftdi/imx93-evk.cfg -f board/imx93-evk.cfg
however I am getting the below error:-
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0 (2021-11-18) [https://github.com/sysprogs/openocd]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
libusb1 09e75e98b4d9ea7909e8837b7a3f00dda4589dc3
For bug reports, read
http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Error: JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all ones
Error: Check JTAG interface, timings, target power, etc.
Error: Trying to use configured scan chain anyway...
Error: imx93.cpu: IR capture error; saw 0x0f not 0x01
Warn : Bypassing JTAG setup events due to errors
Error: Invalid ACK (7) in DAP response
Error: JTAG-DP STICKY ERROR
Can anyone tell me how do I resolve this?
